# Accumulation point of a discrete Spectrum

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory, self-adjoint-operators, closed-graph

Let $L: \text{Dom} (L)\subset L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)\mapsto L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$ be a self-adjoint, closed, and negative operator. I am trying to prove that the discrete spectrum $\sigma_{dis}$ of $L$ can only accumulate at the essential spectrum $\sigma_{ess}$ of $L$.

I am thinking about using only the definition of $\sigma_{dis}$, using the fact that it only includes isolated points. If a sequence $\lambda$ in $\sigma_{dis}$ converges to $\lambda$, then $\lambda$ is not isolated and thus $\lambda$ is in $\sigma_{ess}$.

Is this true on enough? I see in [this reference](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjgw4_yy8_0AhWE66QKHQ-1A6MQFnoECAUQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fd-nb.info%2F1001898664%2F34%2F&usg=AOvVaw0H3wIY4z7_WMbiEYbVdinO) on page 11 proposition 1.1.9 a bit more complicated criteria, that's why I'm doubting about mine.

Thanks for helping me know if I'm mistaken or not!